# MYSQL ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table

Tags: mysql

I get this error and I have no idea why this is my first time using MYSQL and I can't seem to find a solution that works anywhere.

```
CREATE TABLE Orders ( 
 ordID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 sellName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
 itemPrice REAL NOT NULL, 
 ordItems VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
 ordQuantity INT NULL, 
 CONSTRAINT pk_order PRIMARY KEY (ordID), 
 CONSTRAINT fk_ord_sell FOREIGN KEY (sellName) REFERENCES Seller 
(sellName), 
 CONSTRAINT fk_ord_item FOREIGN KEY (itemPrice) REFERENCES Item 
(itemPrice) 
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: are the two tables: `Seller` and `Item`, already created?

Comment: Do you have create table permission?

Comment: Can you show us the Seller and Item create table statements as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with the foreign keys....because i do this:

```
 CREATE TABLE Orders ( 
 ordID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 sellName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
 itemPrice REAL NOT NULL, 
 ordItems VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
 ordQuantity INT NULL, 
 CONSTRAINT pk_order PRIMARY KEY (ordID)
 ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

An let me create the table in a perfect way.

Saludos.